# laravel how to use carbon Period to archive month complete date get

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to archive month date 1 to month end date with.

below code now get this year month complete date 1 to 31 by below code.
but it only gives current year month I want to pass dynamic year month name or month number to archive date list

```
 $this->dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create(now()->startOfMonth(), now()->endOfMonth())->toArray();
 dd($this->dateRange);
```

Result I get:

```
 01-01-2024
 02-01-2024
    ...
 31-01-2024
```

I'm trying to archive month date 1 to month end date in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive that using `->setMonth`:

```
$monthNumber = 1;
$this->dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create(now()->startOfMonth()->setMonth($monthNumber), now()->endOfMonth())->toArray();
```

}

But if you want to work with different years (instead of only the now() year), I recommend a different approach:

```
$year = 2024;  // Replace with the desired year
$month = 5;    // Replace with the desired month number or month name 

// Create a Carbon instance for the first day of the specified month
$startDate = Carbon::create($year, $month, 1)->startOfMonth();

// Create a Carbon instance for the last day of the specified month
$endDate = $startDate->endOfMonth();
$dateRange = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate)->toArray();
dd($dateRange);
```

Comment: what if i whant to pass 2024-1, or 2023-3 how to pass this

Comment: `CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::create(2023, 3), Carbon::create(2024, 1)->endOfMonth())`  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why to use `now()` in this case. Create new objects from scratch, and if you want those months on the current year, pass `null` as first parameter to `create()`:

```
$startMonth = 1;
$endMonth = 3;
$start = Carbon::create(null, $startMonth);
$end = Carbon::create(null, $endMonth)->endOfMonth();
dd(CarbonPeriod::create($start, $end)->toArray());
```

And just use `parse()` to work with month name instead of number:

```
$startMonth = 'January';
$endMonth = 'March';
$start = Carbon::parse($startMonth);
$end = Carbon::parse($endMonth)->endOfMonth();
dd(CarbonPeriod::create($start, $end)->toArray());
```